# How to choose between two models having similar validation score but different training score?

Tags: model-selection, overfitting

I have trained two models, **A** and **B**. **A** has more parameters than **B**. Also **A** has higher *training* score than **B**. However both models have similar *validation* scores. Obviously model **A** overfits.

How do I choose between **A** and **B**?

What if **A** had better *validation* score, but the difference between *training* score and *validation* score were higher?

Comment: Are the training and validation scores cross validated? Why don't you have test dataset to have a test score?

Comment: They are not cross validated. I do have a test dataset but I am not sure if I should use the test score while selecting between two models. The test scores are similar to the validation scores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost every model will have better training score than validation score. The purpose of validation score<sup>1</sup> is to select which model performs the best on unseen data and that is probably the model which you want to use. If multiple models perform equally well on a validation set, then choosing the simplest one makes sense. To wrap it up:

> How do I choose between A and B?

Use the simpler one (**B**).

> What if A had better validation score, but the difference between training score and validation score were higher?

Use the better performing one (**A**).

**Note aside**: You should also consider performing a cross-validation; that way you obtain a *mean validation score* **and** its *variance*. If the model has slightly higher mean validation score but very high variance, you should perhaps choose the worse, but more stable model.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes the term *validation score* is reserved for hyperparameter tuning and early stopping in some models; then the term *test score* is used for model selection.